# Does someone know whether Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.122.1.0 supports everything that version 2.112.2.0

Tags: c#, oracle

I've been using Oracle.DataAccess.dll in ODAC112040Xcopy_64bit for a long time to make .net calls to Oracle, I want to update the assembly to the version from ODAC122010Xcopy_x64. I'm just not sure if it will fully support everything the older version did as it can still be used to connect to older Oracle DBs.

So basically will ODAC112040Xcopy_64bit and ODAC122010Xcopy_x64 be able connect and execute against the same Oracle DBs, with ODAC122010Xcopy_x64 just having new functionality for newer Oracle DBs

Comment: I do not remember seeing any issues with backwards compatibility issues with Oracle (and Oracle Drivers).  Usually the version of Oracle and the Driver (dll) have to be compatible. I've seen issues when drivers other than Oracle are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to connect to an Oracle Database older than 11.2.0, see [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]